# Create grouped-bar using chart.js, php and mysql

Tags: php, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I have table biggest_user in mysql like this:

[image: biggest_user]

and i want to create grouped-bar using chart.js.

I already create code like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<center>


<?php
    include 'conn.php';
    $sql = "Select date, user, sum(total) as total from user_biggest group by date,user";
#       $sql = "SELECT difference, date FROM `biggest_user`";
    $date = $conn->query($sql);
    $user = $conn->query($sql);
    $total = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<canvas id="bar-chart-grouped" width="1000" height="250"></canvas>

<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
                labels: [<?php while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($date)) { echo '"' . $a['date'] . '",'; } ?>],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Total",
          backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
          data: [<?php while($b = mysqli_fetch_array($total)) { echo $b['total'] . ', '; } ?>]
    },

    {
          label: "User",
          backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
          data: [<?php while($c = mysqli_fetch_array($user)) { echo $b['user'] . ', '; } ?>]
    }

      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Biggest User (Megabytes)'
      }
    }
});
</script>
```

but the result chart is like this:

[image: grouped-bar]

I think it's not grouped-bar chart. but i don't know what's wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know much about `php`. Therefore I can only partially answer your question.

`data.labels` should contain an entry for each day. What you further need is one `dataset` for each user and that's it.

Please take a look at below code snippet and see how it could work.

```js
new Chart("chart", {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["01-Sep-20", "02-Sep-20", "03-Sep-20"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "cs",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      data: [229, 200, 198]
    },
    {
      label: "finance",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      data: [162, 150, 178]
    },
    {
      label: "credit",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [89, 156, 90]
    },
    {
      label: "it",
      backgroundColor: "orange",
      data: [89, 55, 112]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code is right if the data is not dynamic. But thank you for your answer because it enlightened me.

Comment: It's working but, How to add title in Y axis ?